# org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions doesn't work with equals

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, expression, e4

I'm currently starting out with with Eclipse e4 SWT and have a problem with core expressions.

I'm trying to set up a core expression to optionally display popup menu items from a treeview.

When I define the expression as instanceof MyObject, it works fine; the menu item displays if instanceof is MyObject, doesn't show when the instance of some other object.

I then tried to show the menu item as equals to a value and I can't get it to work.

The menu item won't show at all, even when the value is correct.  I have an Integer range form zero to 4 so want to show certain menu items for a particular Integer value.

I've tried comparing the value to Integer and String but no menu items show, yet when I change it to instanceof Integer or String, they display.

Can anyone tell me how equals is supposed to work?

Comment: What variable are you working 'with'? Show us your definition.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` will only work with objects that are of type String, Boolean, Integer or Float. For example this from the Ant editor:

```xml
<extension
       point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
    <definition
          id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.activeAntEditor">
       <with
             variable="activeEditorId">
          <equals
                value="org.eclipse.ant.ui.internal.editor.AntEditor">
          </equals>
       </with>
    </definition>
 </extension>
```

This is testing the variable `activeEditorId` which is a String and matching it with the String value 'org.eclipse.ant.ui.internal.editor.AntEditor'.

Variables such as the current selection are usually not one of the supported types so 'equals' will return false.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I still don't understand how equals works.

Comment: Is the value a class name or a literal value?  Does the AntEditor have some method that returns the value to compare?  All I want is as follows: <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
      <definition
            id="au.com.mytest.framework.plan.definition.3">
         <with
               variable="plan_level">
            <equals
                  value="3">
            </equals>
         </with>
      </definition>
   </extension>

Comment: Apologies for formatting.  Every time I hit the enter key, to get a new line, it submits text.

Comment: The value is a string, 'activeEditorId' gives a string. Where does the variable 'plan_level' come from?

Comment: In my treeview listener, I set the variable via the context, viz. context.set("plan_level", new Integer(3));

Comment: I assume 'context' is the IEclipseContext for the part. Testing here this does work, but only if the part context is the active context. If some other part is active the variable won't be defined in that part's context.

Comment: OK, I think I know what happened.  I had to remove the core expression from the handled menu item then re-add it to make it  "active". I'd been changing the expression definition but not re-adding it to the menu item and it seems the menu handler wasn't using the latest definition.  Possible caching issue?

Comment: Thank you Greg for your time; I've definitely learned something about core expressions and definitions.